# In Oracle, how do I convert a number such as 1 to a string such as "1st"?

Tags: sql, oracle, string-formatting

I'd like to format a number as "1st", "2nd", "4th", "9th", etc. Is there an Oracle function that will do this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying, but it seems like the following should work just fine (for integers) and is a lot more readable than converting to a date and back:

```
select case 
       when initial_extent is null then null
       when substr(initial_extent,-2,1) = '1' 
            then initial_extent || 'th'
       else case substr(initial_extent,-1,1)
            when '1' then initial_extent || 'st'
            when '2' then initial_extent || 'nd'
            when '3' then initial_extent || 'rd'
            else initial_extent || 'th'
            end
       end as formatted_number
from user_tables
```

Comment: The date-based approach is cool, but this is what I ended up with. Works regardless of what number you throw at it. The date approach might be better if you need different results by language.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming the value supplied is numeric, rather than DATE, you can use [TO_CHAR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) but you have to convert the numeric value to a string, then a DATE (Julian) before ultimately formatting it:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1', 'dd'), 'ddth')
  FROM DUAL
```

Result:

```
01st
```

When testing, using 'd' for the format didn't return expected results because the value is interpreted as a Julian date.  Either substring the output to remove the leading zero, or provide a full date string (doesn't matter to the TO_CHAR because it's only interested in the day of the month):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-dd'), 'dth')
  FROM DUAL
```

Because calendar days end at 31, use the year value instead to handle numbers greater than 31:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('32-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-dd'), 'yyth')
  FROM DUAL
```

Result:

```
32nd
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but wouldn't this return `1th` instead of `1st`?

Comment: Yes, I was wrong; the [Oracle docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#autoId10) state that `TH` is a valid format element suffix.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds: S'all good.  'TH' is only available for dates when I was testing on 10g.

Comment: one more problem is here.... you can't call this query for above 31 number..... just try for 32 you will get an error that 'day of month should be between 1 and last day of month' :) .... is there any alternative to conver number to this kind of case??

Comment: @pratik garg: See update - use the year rather than day of month

Comment: good idea... :) ... but what about 10000 ??
i was looking for number the same question and that time I got this .... this is looking very good but what about this kind of case

Comment: @pratik garg: You're welcome to contribute your answer, and address edge cases the OP has yet to communicate in it.

Answer (score -1):

```
select  substr( to_char( to_date( abs( decode( mod( l_value, 10 ), 0, 4, mod( l_value , 10 )  ) ), 'YYYY' ), 'YTH' ), 2 ) as value
from    dual
```

Replace l_value with appropriate, hmmm, value. Should cover any numbers.